# Key event not caught the 1st time after a dialog is displayed

Tags: gwt, ckeditor

In catching a "key" event in CKEditor, we have a case where a dialog is displayed if a key is typed within a certain HTML span.

After the dialog is dismissed, the 1st key typed does not register on the key listener, but all subsequent keys DO register.

Is this something anyone else has seen?

We're using CKEditor in its inline form, in an application framework based on GWT (Google Web Toolkit).  It's possible that GWT is somehow messing with event handling, but I'm not sure how that might be.

I tried setting the event priority very high, but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After I noticed that the text insertion cursor was not visible until after I tried to type a character after the dialog was dismissed, I tried explicitly setting focus after the dialog is dismissed.  This ended up fixing the issue.

I'm not sure why focus would not be on CKEditor until after I did that, or until after a character is typed, but that appears to be the fix.